# How to properly convert IQueryable datetime?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I've spent a couple of hours trying to get this right.

I'm trying to copy values from my database to local variables in order to get a time span (in minutes) between two dates. That last part I think I figured it out, but on the timespan line I'm getting an error:

> DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types

For what I understood so far, `end_time` and `start_time` variables are in the "IQueryable" format. How can I convert them to "normal" `datetime` variables?

```
var end_time = from r in db.Reservations
               where r.CustomUserID.Equals(user.Id)
               select r.EndDate;

var start_time = from r in db.Reservations
                 where r.CustomUserID.Equals(user.Id)
                 select r.BeginDate;

TimeSpan timespan = end_time.First() - start_time.First();
```

Thank you in advance for any help :) Cheers

Comment: is this Entity Framework? and are `CustomUserID` and `user.ID` `Int32`?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code. Please [edit] post to avoid `var` (use "use explicit type" quick refactoring in VS to fix it), consider to have each value (like `end_time.First() `) in separate variable and make sure to verify what line actually produces the error (as error you claim is unlikely to happen on the line you've said)

Comment: Q: Are you using EF, is `db` a DBContext, andis  Reservations a DBSet?  Q: Have you looked at end_time and start_time in the  MSVS debugger?  What are their values?  Q: Do the queries actually return anything?  Or is that the problem?  PLEASE: Update your post and answer these questions.

Comment: Use debugger to see the type of start time and end time. Error indicates that these two values cant be subtracted like that

Comment: Please replace `var` with the actual type

Comment: Is this the same as: `var timespan = db.Reservations.First(r => r.CustomUserID.Equals(user.Id)).Select(r => r.EndDate - r.BeginDate);`

Comment: You are calling `.First` on each of `end_time` and `start_time`.  That will convert them from being `IQueryables` into (I'm assuming) `DateTimes` (or throw if the result is empty).  Is this not working?  Try creating temporary variables for the result of each of the calls to `.First` and see what happens (in particular, see what type your temporaries are)

Comment: I think, all of you missing that the error has something to do with this `where r.CustomUserID.Equals(user.Id)`. This is differed execution and when `First` is called, `equals` is not translated well by EF into SQL. I've had this before. See comment number 2 from the top

Comment: on the general comment, if you expect same record from where `CustomUserID = Id`, why not just `select  (r.BeginDate, r.EndDate)` ?

Comment: In terms of readability, when I see a variable called `end_time`, I expect it to be a temporal value, not a query expression. Consider calling `.First()` on the expressions and assigning the result to the variables. That said, **T.S.** makes an excellent point in that you don't need to hit the database twice for the same row.

Comment: I am using EF, and db is a BDContext, Reservations is a DBSET. The queries should return something, since i'm using the same queries to get other data (not dates).

Answer (score 4):

I'll take a risk to answer this because I've seen something like this before in my own code

Since LINQ is based on a concept of differed execution, you don't get anything but expression from your particular query till you call `end_time.First() - start_time.First()`. This is when your LINQ being translated into SQL by entity framework and DB call is made.

Looking at the error quality, I believe that `r.CustomUserID.Equals(user.Id)` construct causing it. Try changing it to `r.CustomUserID == user.Id`. I bet this will solve the issue.

Other point here, if you expect same record from `where` condition `CustomUserID = Id`, why not just select tuple or an anonymous type containing both dates?

```
(r.BeginDate, r.EndDate)
new {a = r.BeginDate, b = r.EndDate}
```

This will save a trip to database

Comment: Note that selecting both Begin and End at the same time from the same record is actually correctness issue as databases are not required to return items in the same order for every query (unless you order by some unique key).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I pointed out that if basically the `where` condition guarantee to return same record (i.e.) `id` is unique, then 2 fields should be selected together. If you ask me, what sense makes to select random first and another random first from 2 different fields and calculate the difference - nonsense. I bet that OP where clause is missing another identifier. So, my suggestion is mostly hypothetical one.

Comment: T.S. sure. It's just the remark in the post looks like a performance recommendation when it is actually required for correctness in the "if you expect same record" case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one of the [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487052.aspx). So, for your statement, something like:

```
var uid = user.Id;
var time_diff = (from r in db.Reservations
                       where r.CustomUserID.Equals(uid)
                       select SqlFunctions.DateDiff("minute", r.BeginDate, r.EndDate)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: No man. The problem is still here `r.CustomUserID.Equals(uid)`

Comment: what is type of CustomUserID and user.Id? I guess EF is not able to compare those types that is what causing the issue, Maybe you can make both the properties of same type and then it will work